# null check NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have two strings both with value **null**. But when I am comparing the string I have some problem :

```
if([textField.text isEqualToString:str])
{
//Some code
}
```

Both are **null** but control does not get into if condition.
Please help.
Thanks,
Stone

Comment: from where you get the str value. Please provide more information for understand your problem.

Comment: @hotlicks: thnx for correcting me. Of course , u r r8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[nil anyMethodName]` always returns zero/NO.  You need to compare with `==` to handle the null case (but still compare with some form of `isEquals` to handle the non-null case).

Answer (score 0):

`isEqualToString` works with `NSString`, a pointers (`textField.text` and `str`) that are null do not point to objects. Sending a message to nil is allowed and returns nil.

In a case such as this first check that the pointers point to valid objects, in they case `NSString` objects.

Perhaps:

```
if((textField.text==nil && str==nil) || [textField.text isEqualToString:str])
{
//Some code
}
```

Comment: Or you could make the first test simply `textField.text==str`.

Comment: Yes but then it looks like addresses are being compared and I don't like code that is somewhat misleading. My feeling is that `nil` is more clear.

Comment: Well, addresses ARE being compared.  If the two strings happen to be one and the same then the second test will be short-circuited, which is quite fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do,

but if you want to do something when textField is blank you can write

```
if([textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
//Some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
NSString *s1 = nil;
NSString *s2 = nil;

// you can compare two nils
if (s1 == s2)
{
    NSLog(@"==");
}

// s1 is nil so you shouldn't send a message to it
if ([s1 isEqualToString:s2])
{
    NSLog(@"isEqualToString");
}
```

Outputs:

```
2011-12-19 07:33:54.651 Craplet[2845:707] ==
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what do you want to do. I assume you want to check whether text field is empty.

When a text field is empty one of two values may have be assigned. They may be @"" or nil.
So you have to check for both

```
if ([@"" isEqualToString: textField.text] || !textField.text) {
        NSLog(@"Text Field is empty");
}
```